# If a child object is released in the dealloc of a parent object, why would the child object's weak reference to the parent be nil*

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, reference, weak-references

***because the child is released within the `dealloc` of the parent, wouldn't that imply that the parent object still exists, and that the child's weak reference back to the parent should still be valid?**

I have a parent object, a `NSViewController` subclass, which owns another object, a `NSWindowController` subclass.

```
@interface MyViewController : NSViewController
@property (strong) MyWindowController *myWindowController;
```

The `NSWindowController` subclass has a weak reference back to the `NSViewController`

```
@interface MyWindowController : NSWindowController
@property (weak) MyViewController *myViewController;
```

Inside of `MyViewController`, I have overridden `-dealloc`:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
   [self.myWindowController close];
   self.myWindowController = nil;
}
```

And inside of `MyWindowController`, I am adding/removing observers inside of the `init`/`close` methods.

```
//INIT:
[self.myViewController addObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(selectedObjects)) options:kObservingOptions context:nil];


//CLOSE:
[self.myViewController removeObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(selectedObjects))];
```

Now here's the confusing part.

The order of operations on deallocation goes like this:

- `-[MyViewController dealloc]`
- `-[MyWindowController close]`
- `-[MyViewController removeObserver:MyWindowController]`

BUT, at the point of `-[MyWindowController close]`, the weak reference to `MyViewController` is `nil`.  Even though it was `MyViewController` that called `close` in the first place.

This causes issues because the observer isn't properly removed, and later throws exceptions and sometimes even crashes.

What it **looks** like, is that the retain count to `MyViewController` had already been decremented to 0 before the `-dealloc` is called, so `MyWindowController`'s weak reference to it gets set to `nil`.  But that doesn't make sense to me because it would seem like the retain count would decrement **after** `-dealloc`, and also even if that weren't the case, would the weak reference be `nil`?

It may be possible that this is just a weird interaction w/ `NSViewController` owning a `NSWindowController`, but that doesn't make much sense to me either

Why is the weak `@property` == `nil`?

Comment: It is always perilous to try to reason about retain counts. That said, the retain count never gets decremented to zero. When a `-release` is done on an object whose retain count is 1, weak references are nilled and it is deallocated. You say "it would seem like the retain count would decrement **after** `-dealloc`". There is no "after `-dealloc`". After `-dealloc` there is no more object to have a retain count. As to when to close the window, perhaps do it in `-viewWillDisappear`, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's [documentation on ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> A weak reference does not extend the lifetime of the object it points to, and automatically becomes nil when there are no strong references to the object.

Note, that it doesn't say "when an object is deallocated."  If an objects `dealloc` method is being called, then all strong references have, by definition, been removed.

Furthermore, you shouldn't be calling methods on objects that have already been deallocated.  You should find a way to unregister your observer before the object is deallocated.

Comment: Makes total sense, thanks.  I don't think I want to have a strong reference from `MyWindowController` to `MyViewController` right?  So would there be a problem if I added/removed observers in `MyViewController`, instead of `MyWindowController`?  That way I could do `[self removeObserver:self.myWindowController`]` within the `-dealloc` of `MyViewController`, and self would not be nil correct?